# Phonegap-plugin barcodescanner for iOS: no support for PDF417?

Tags: iphone, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

I'm building a barcodescanner for both Android and iPhone, which needs to support several formats, including PDF417. I got the phonegap plugin from [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) working on Android (is working nicely, really cool), and looking into the iPhone/iOS version. But it seems [the PDF417 format is not supported](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/284) (yet).

Does anyone have an idea if the PDF417 format will be supported soon, or I should consider building something by myself? Or are their other plugins/libraries for phonegap that'll integrate smoothly?

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477735/how-to-scan-pdf417-2d-barcode) ZXing has alpha-level support for PDF417 barcodes. That might not help you much for Phonegap, though.

Comment: I don't have an answer for barcodescanner phonegab-plugin, but if you want to explore other PDF417 phonegap plugins, I can recommend the one that was developed by a team I'm working for: https://github.com/PDF417

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is supported in iOS7, you can use AVCapture and AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code.